# WCF data service hosting in Windows Form

Tags: wcf

I want to host a WCF Data Service (formerly known as ADO.NET data Service) in windows form.Is it possible? If yes,then is there any blog, which talks about it?
I know WCF can be hosted in Windows Form, but I am not sure about WCF data service, as all the examples I see, is asking to create ASP.NET web project.

-Brajesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very easy to host a WCF Data Service in a WinForms application (or in my case a unit test).

```
// add reference to System.Data.Services

// identify your endpoint uri
Uri endpoint = new Uri("http://localhost:12345/MyDataService");
// create the data service host
DataServiceHost host = new DataServiceHost(typeof(MyDataService), new Uri[] { endpoint });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your solution worked and saved lot of my time.
-Brajesh

Comment: @user158598, then why didn't you mark the question as answered?