# WCF Data Service vs. WCF Service Library

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I noticed I cannot add a WCF Data Service (.svc file) to a WCF Service Library project in Visual Studio 2010. I'm a bit of a newb to WCF and was wondering how/why I should put my WCF Data Service into its own assembly.

Comment: WCF Data Service can **only** be added to a web application (and possibly a "Web site") project - at least with the Visual Studio templates....

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can host a WCF Data Service in your own assembly - with a few little tricks. Doing so makes your solution cleaner - it separates the various pieces into more manageable bits, so I would definitely recommend doing this.

Here's how:

- put your data model (EF Data Model) into its own assembly, let's call it `DataModel`
- create a new class library project (call it `MyDataServiceHost`)
- add a few references:

  - your `DataModel` assembly with the data layer
  - `System.ServiceModel`
  - `System.ServiceModel.Web`
  - `System.Data.Services.Client`
  - `System.Data.Services` - you cannot pick this from the usual `Add Reference` dialog under the .NET category - you need to browse for the assembly file. Find the directory `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0` (or `C:\Program Files (x86)\...` on a 64-bit machine) and pick the `System.Data.Services.dll` inside it
- add a new class to that class library and call it e.g. `YourDataService.cs` - it will look something like this:

  ```
  using System.Data.Services;
  using System.Data.Services.Common;

  using DataModel;

  namespace MyDataServiceHost
  {
      public class YourDataService : DataService<YourModelEntities>
      {
          // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
          public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
          {
              // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
              // Examples:
              config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
              config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  You can name the class anything you like, and it has to derive from `DataService<T>` where `T` is the name of your data model; if you're using Entity Framework, it's the name of your object context class - typically something like `(database)Entities` or whatever you picked when you created the EDM
- add another class to your new project, call it `MyDataServiceHost.cs` and it will look something like this:

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Data.Services;

  using DataModel;

  namespace MyDataServiceHost
  {
      public class MyDataServiceHost
      {
          public static void LaunchDataService(string baseAddress)
          {
              Uri[] baseAddresses = new Uri[1];
              baseAddresses[0] = new Uri(baseAddress);

              using(DataServiceHost host = new DataServiceHost(typeof(YourDataService), baseAddresses))
              {
                  host.Open();
                  Console.WriteLine("DataService up and running.....");

                  Console.ReadLine();
                  host.Close();
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  It instantiates a DataServiceHost, which is derived from WebServiceHost (which in turn is derived from ServiceHost) and it will spin up the WCF Data Service runtime for you.
- now you can start up your WCF Data Service from any app using:

  ```
  MyDataServiceHost.LaunchDataService("http://localhost:4444/YourService");
  ```
- last thing to remember: the app that you use to launch the WCF Data Service **must have** the connection string (the EDM connection string, if you're using Entity Framework) in its `app.config` (or `web.config`) in order for this to work!

Comment: Yes I saw this in a previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768145/create-wcf-data-service-for-use-in-service-host Will this create the svc file?

Comment: @Ryan: no - there's no *.svc file needed, since you create your `DataServiceHost` yourself and you define the base address where your service is reachable in your code - no point in having an *.svc file

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'm not sure this is the way I want to go or not.

Comment: @marc_c actually whats the difference between doing this and just creating a WCF service application?

Comment: @Ryan: WCF **Data** Services is 1) a REST-based service ("normal" WCF services in a service app are **SOAP**-based), and 2) the WCF Data Services have a bunch of additional capabilities that a regular, bare-bones WCF service doesn't have

Comment: Ahh I see, thats very good to know. What if I need this WCF Data Service for an iPhone client or some other non Microsoft platform? Is it possible to still launch it or no? This is why I was thinking mainly of a WCF Service application with a WCF Data Service inside of it, or does that defeat the purpose?

Comment: @Ryan: WCF **Data** Services (being **REST** based) is ideal for phones, devices, non-MS platforms - as **clients** calling that service. It builds on top of WCF - so having WCF Data Services has WCF "underneath" - no point in having both (if you have a WCF Data Service, you also have a WCF service at the same time).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4957/discussion-between-ryan-and-marc-s)